# Resize column headers in Angular ag-grid on sort

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When I click on my header row to sort a column, it adds an up/down arrow to the header, to the right of my header text. This is making the header text truncate.

Is there a way to have the header width autosize to accommodate the up/down arrow added when sorting?

[image: Before clicking header to sort, the header text is "Date Updated"]
[image: After clicking header to sort, the header text becomes truncated to just "Date"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a fixed width to column so it can accommodate both text and arrow icon -

```
{ headerName: 'Col C', field: 'c', width: 100, editable: false, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter' }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using autoSizeAllColumns which conflicted with setting width directly. The solution is to use autoSizeColumns and pass in the columns that you don't want to set the width directly for.